# Problem compiling AES-NI instructions on OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: assembly, osx-snow-leopard, gnu-assembler, libressl

On my OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) Mac mini 2.53Ghz (Late 2009 Intel P8700) I have tried to compile libressl-2.8. Configuration finished smoothly but during the compilation of **./crypto/aes/aesni-macosx-x86_64.S** it failed with

```
"no such instruction: `aesenc %xmm1,%xmm2"
```

Apparently the GNU AS (**Apple Inc version cctools-773~33, GNU assembler version 1.38**) was unable to recognize AES-NI specific instructions. I 've upgraded to the latest GNU Binutils version 2.25 and the same error came up. Sure, I could pass this step with **--no-asm** directive but I'd like to compile it with assembly codes. The Mac mini in question does support AES-NI set because I've tried compiling the same AES-NI codes from an OS X 10.7 external harddisk on the same computer and it got compiled without any error. So I guess it's an issue with the OS. How can I compile the AES-NI codes on Snow Leopard? Thank you.

Comment: what is the version of the C compiler? Clang has its own assembler, so updating the binutils doesn't chsnge anything.

Comment: Forgot to talk about the C compiler version. Well it was first the original Apple GCC compiler which came with the Xcode, it was version 4.2 or something. Then I've downloaded and compiled GCC-6.1.0 but the assemblies didn't get compiled with it either. When I tried compiling them from the OSX 7 Lion image, they got compiled in a hearbeat. So its almost certain that it's about the OS.